# I want to override theme node.tpl.php file with node--[content-type].tpl.php in my custom module

Tags: 7, theming

I am making a new custom module. and i have 1 content type called city management(city-management).
I want to override theme node.tpl.php file with node--city-management.tpl.php in my custom module.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes of course. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Just to be sure I understood the question: Do you want to use a template file contained in your module directory, or in the theme directory?

Comment: template file content in the module directory.

Comment: In this case, the question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by providing Drupal with a content type template suggestion through [hook_theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7). It uses the same 'node--contentname' formalism you are used to in theme templates. This method is IMHO preferred if your module also creates the content type you're theming.

Comment: `hook_theme()` doesn't override the existing theme functions, such as the theme function used to render nodes.